# How to config webpack to load custom fonts into storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook

I'm new to webpack and I'm trying to load custom fonts into stroybook v4 following this tutorial https://medium.com/@mushti_dev/hey-e6faa20b910a

The workspace structure looks like this (create-react-app + storybook)

```
my-project/
  .storybook
     config.js
     preview-hrad.html
     webpack.config.js
  fonts
    MyCustomFont.woff
  src
    components
       Title.js
    containers
    styles
       MyCustomFont.woff
    index.js
  stories
```

When loading the font from the **styles folder** in src, the config is as follows:

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  // fonts
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        }
      }
    ],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
  });

  return config;
};
```

preview-head.html

```css
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
    src: url('styles/MyCustomFont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```

Title.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const Title = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 style={{fontFamily: 'MyCustomFont'}}>{title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Title;
```

My question is how to load MyCustomFont.woff from the **fonts folder** ?

I tried to update the webpack config with  `name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',` and the css style with `src: url('fonts/MyCustomFont.woff') format('woff');` but I'm having hard time matching the correct font path.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue on [`storybook v6.1`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction), then realised there are actually two font areas to setup:

- iframe preview fonts (components preview fonts in `preview-head.html`)
- storybook dashboard fonts (dashboard navigation fonts in `manager-head.html`)

> What I did:

- make a copy of `preview-head.html` and rename to `manager-head.html`
- ensure the font url specified in `@font-face` is relative to static folder path specified in npm scripts with `-s`
- I did not change webpack config in `main.js`

> my folder structure

```sh
|- .storybook/
   |- ...
   |- preview-head.html
   |- manager-head.html
|- src/
   |- ...
   |- fonts/
      |- font-name.otf
```

> `preview-head.html` and `manager-head.html`

```html
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('fonts/font-name.otf') format('opentype');
    ...
  }
</style>
```

> `package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "storybook": "start-storybook ... -s ./src",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s ./src"
  }
}
```

Comment: This suggestion changes if I am using create-react-app? Because I haven't being able to make it work. Also checking https://github.com/mydatahack/mdh-design-system-storybook-typescript but can't make it work yet.

Comment: @AlexisDuran in your `*-head.html` file you can try something like this:
`<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
    ...
  }
</style>
` then in your `package.json` you should have `"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src"` and `"build-storybook": "build-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src"`

Comment: I ending up by use S3 to allocate my fonts and then from there everything was smooth. Hopefully either yours or my response help someone in the future!