# How can I use static assets on scss with storybook?

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-4, storybook

I have a scss library under `styles/` folder where I have code like this:

```
// Variables
$path-to-img: "/img" !default;
$path-to-fonts: "/fonts" !default;

// Example use case
.bg-pattern-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, $black 100%), url('#{$path-to-img}/patterns/pattern-2.png');
}
```

In Next.js, I have all the static assets under the `public/` folder, so:

```
public/
------- img/
------- fonts/
------- ...
```

But when I try to run `start-storybook -p 9000` it gives me an error:

[image]

It makes a lot of sense that this error is thrown, but how can I really solve this?

With webpack in specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

First of, you can run `yarn storybook --debug-webpack` to take a quick look at the structure of Webpack configuration.

After some debugging, I could see that the `publicPath` was `""`, so this means that the assets needed to be in `.storybook` folder under it the `/img` and `/fonts` folders

Why?

Because the html output that renders the Storybook app is on that same path with injected CSS files, and one of them is the css given by the sass-loader.

Solution:

```js
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Add Sass to storybook
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../styles"),
      use: [
        {
          loader: "style-loader",
        },
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            url: false, // This was the important key ** see explanation
          },
        },
        {
          loader: "sass-loader",
        },
      ],
    });

    // Copy all assets to publicPath
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/fonts"),
            to: "./fonts", 
          },
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/img"),
            to: "./img", 
          },
        ],
      })
    );

    return config;
  },
```

`options {url: false}`
This was the key to my problem. Well, basically when you have:

```
// Example use case
.bg-pattern-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, $black 100%), url('#{$path-to-img}/patterns/pattern-2.png');
}
```

the css-loader will create his own urls, so the injected css will have the wrong path to the images.

By disabling it, we can then *copy* those assets with [copy-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to the publicPath of webpack, where will all function accordingly.

Comment: anyone else facing this issue should see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66806281/1235675)