# Add @fontface to Storybook

Tags: fonts, font-face, storybook

I have a Storybook created in a create-react-app and I want to add a font-face to it. My components are using css-modules (maybe that is useful information).

So, I have created a webpack.config.js inside .storybook and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  });

  return config;
};
```

and in preview-head.html (inside .storybook) I have

```
<style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'WalsheimPro';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url('shared/fonts/GTWalsheimProMedium.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
</style>
```

My font does not work, any idea why?
Any other info you need to help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: There's an answer here that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185735/how-to-config-webpack-to-load-custom-fonts-into-storybook/66806281#66806281 
You may also be using a src path that's incorrect or unreachable. Storybook docs have some info about relative paths here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets

Comment: Thanks! it worked with just changing 
the paths to ./src instead of public :)

```"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s ./src",```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I did not need the webpack.config.js file. I deleted it, but changed my paths in package.json from public to ./src

```
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s ./src",
```

Check the answer above for links :)

Comment: This one worked for me too, Why isn't anyone talking about it. @sanne you are simply great!

Comment: This is now [ ⚠️Deprecated ]. use new solution by Serving your public dir using `staticDirs: ['../public']`

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that I was importing my `@font-face {...}` rules on my `App.tsx` but not on my storybook config which is represented in the `preview.js` file.

The solution was to import my css @font-face rules inside the `preview.js` (if you dont have this file you should create it [reference](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering) )

// *preview.js* file

```
import 'scss/myFontsDeclaration.css';
...
```

// *myFontsDeclaration.css*

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/GoogleFonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Serving static files via Storybook Configuration

We recommend serving static files via Storybook to ensure that your components always have the assets they need to load. We recommend this technique for assets that your components often use, like logos, fonts, and icons.

Configure a directory (or a list of directories) where your assets live when starting Storybook. Use the `staticDirs` configuration element in your main Storybook configuration file (i.e., `.storybook/main.js`) to specify the directories:

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [],
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
};
```

Here `../public` is your static directory.

You can also pass a list of directories separated by commas without spaces instead of a single directory.

```js
staticDirs: ['../public', '../static']
```

Or even use a configuration object to define the directories:

```js
staticDirs: [{ from: '../my-custom-assets/images', to: '/assets' }]
```

---

#### [ ⚠️Deprecated ] Serving static files via Storybook CLI

Using `--static-dir` or `-s` option with Storybook CLI is deprecated. It is recommended to use [Storybook static directory configuration option](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook-configuration) instead. But for older versions or reference:

The sb init script creates two Storybook scripts in our `package.json`. Update both to serve the public directory (where your Fonts and Next.js images are kept). The CLI option we use for this is `-s` or `--static-dir`.

```js
// package.json

"scripts": {
-    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
-    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
+    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./public",
+    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
}
```

Find more CLI options in our [CLI options doc](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/cli-options). And learn more about [Serving Static Files via Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook).

---

**Read more:**
[Get started with Storybook and Next.js](https://storybook.js.org/blog/get-started-with-storybook-and-next-js/) By *Michael Chan*
[Images, fonts, and assets](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook-configuration) By *Storybook Docs*